# How can I render a fully bundled react app inside of an iframe?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, iframe, create-react-app

High level overview:

I'm building an SDK to allow people to build custom tools into our existing application. These custom tools will be hosted in an iframe for security reasons. They need to be able to receive data from the parent window, and communicate changes back to the parent when the pertinent data is manipulated within the iframe.

How do I go about accessing the built executable files from the custom tool within my parent app so as to render them within the iframe? Happy to provide code snippets if useful, but more looking for a starter direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The React element below renders in an iframe, which needs to include [`react.production.min.js`](https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js) and [`react-dom.production.min.js`](https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js) along with your Babel-transpiled React app:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  (<h1>Hello!</h1>),
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Notice the call to `ReactDOM` is different when actually included in the iframe because it has been transpiled from JSX to regular ES6, but otherwise it's pretty much copy-paste:

[image: Chrome DevTools.]

Comment: This is awesome, thanks so much! How are you getting the transpiled react app code into a place where the iframe can consume it? I was trying to go through npm run build and then taking the build folder, dropping that into my project, and somehow getting the pathing to work dynamically.

Comment: You have to set up a babel script in your `package.json`, it's a huge pain IMO but you can find the instructions [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/#jsx-and-react). If you're working with something small, you can actually do it manually at: https://babeljs.io/repl

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you, but you've been a gold mine so far. I can't thank you enough! Can you think of how this might be possible to do with something like a full webpack bundle with all of its own dependencies and an html entry point? And/or a full webpack bundle with a single executable file.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not that familiar with that whole workflow (I'm a Closure Compiler man myself), but it looks like there's a pretty good tutorial up at: https://www.valentinog.com/blog/babel/